# Error Code: 1093 Table 'transactions' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help ....

```
UPDATE transactions SET `tr_code` = 
(SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tr_code,  '-', 
(LENGTH(tran.tr_code) - LENGTH( REPLACE(tran.tr_code, '-', '' ) ) ) ), '-' , tran.id) FROM transactions tran
WHERE tran.id = 710) WHERE id = 710;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the subquery at all:

```
UPDATE transactions
    SET `tr_code` = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tr_code,  '-', 
                                           LENGTH(tr_code) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tr_code, '-', '' ))
                                          ), '-' , id
                          ) 
    WHERE id = 710;
```